# Trying to display a matplotlib image histogram onto a tkinter window

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

Trying to output a colour histogram from inputted images on to a tkinter GUI window but can't find any advice. Seen ways to put other graphs on but not specifically histograms. Thanks for any advice!

```
import imageio.v3 as iio
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg)
from tkinter import *

image = iio.imread(uri = (r"C:\Users\System_2\Sample_image.PNG"))

def histogram():
    # tuple to select colors of each channel line
    colors = ("red", "green", "blue")

# create the histogram plot, with three lines, one for
# each color
plt.figure()
plt.xlim([0, 256])
for channel_id, color in enumerate(colors):
    histogram, bin_edges = np.histogram(
        image[:, :, channel_id], bins=256, range=(0, 2000)
    )
    plt.plot(bin_edges[0:-1], histogram, color=color)

#axis labels
plt.xlabel("Color value")
plt.ylabel("Pixel count")

#plots the histogram in a matplotlib GUI
plt.plot(bin_edges[0:-1], histogram)
plt.show()

histogram()


#tkinter gui
def window():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("500x400")
    root.title("Histogram")


    root.mainloop()

window()
```

Been able to output other graphs on the GUI window but simply can't get it to work with this colour histogram. Always seem to get errors, fix them, and get a different error. Also, can't find anything to do with histograms and tkinter online. Thanks for any help you can give

Answer (score 0):

1. Save the matplotlib image

```
image_name = "Temporary Image.png"
plt.savefig(image_name)
plt.close()
```

2. Plot that image in tkinter window

```
pic = PhotoImage(file = image_name)
image_label = Label(root, image = pic)
image_label.pack()
```

3. Remove the image using os module

```
import os
os.remove(image_name)
```

Below is the complete code

```
import imageio.v3 as iio
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg)
from tkinter import *
import os

image = iio.imread(uri = (r"C:\Users\System_2\Sample_image.PNG"))

# tuple to select colors of each channel line
colors = ("red", "green", "blue")

# create the histogram plot, with three lines, one for each color
plt.figure()
plt.xlim([0, 256])
for channel_id, color in enumerate(colors):
    histogram, bin_edges = np.histogram(image[:, :, channel_id], bins=256, range=(0, 2000))
    plt.plot(bin_edges[0:-1], histogram, color=color)

#axis labels
plt.xlabel("Color value")
plt.ylabel("Pixel count")

#plots the histogram in a matplotlib GUI
plt.plot(bin_edges[0:-1], histogram)
image_name = "Temporary Image.png"
plt.savefig(image_name)
plt.close()

#tkinter gui
def window():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Histogram")
    pic = PhotoImage(file = image_name)
    image_label = Label(root, image = pic)
    image_label.pack()
    os.remove(image_name)
    root.mainloop()

window()
```